# Blocks, factors and treatments in designed experiments

Tags: terminology, experiments, notation

I have recently began studying a course on Designed Experiments and am having some trouble understanding some of the terminology. I've looked at some other answers on the site and I think that I am understanding correctly, but would like some clarification (and potentially more detail if there is anything of note).

I have seen that **"factors"** refer to a structure that splits units into groups. I can also see that **"treatments"** are a description of what can be applied to experimental units and that **"blocks"** divide up the experimental units into groups of a similar structure.

My understanding from a previous answer is that factors can be split up into two categories. Treatment factors and block factors. I believe that treatment factors are those that we are interested in investigating the impact of and block factors are those that are necessary for the setup of the experiment but are not of any interest in our experiment.

My question is whether or not this simplified understanding of blocks, factors, and treatments is an accurate model for me to use in my head when trying to understand these concepts and if there is potentially a better way to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rationale expressed in the question is correct. A more useful book would be Box, Hunter & Hunter than the books listed in the question [(see here for a more complete list of book recommendations)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30446/11887). This book explains the concepts in more detail and focusses on examples rather than the notably abstract approach of the other two books. One principle from this book is "Block what you can, randomize what you cannot" in other
words: sources of heterogeneity in experimental material is used to define blocks.